# I want this activity to auto refresh itself after every 3 sec but it is giving me error

Tags: android, listview, android-volley, handler, runnable

I am parsing the data retrieved from an API and then showing it in a list view. I have also included a swipeToRefreshLayout. I want the list to automatically update the information after every 2 seconds.

Error :  : Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.io.File android.content.Context.getCacheDir()' on a null object reference
This errror is in this line -

RequestQueue requestQueue= Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

I don't know much about handler. i think i have not used it at the correct place.

Here is the complete code :

```
public class BitbnsPrice extends AppCompatActivity {

private TextView mtv1;
private ListView list;
ArrayList<String> price=null;
private int mInterval = 5000;
private Handler mHandler;
private SwipeRefreshLayout swipe2refresh;


protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    swipe2refresh= (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipe2refresh);
    swipe2refresh.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            swipe2refresh.setRefreshing(true);
            DataFromExchange();
            swipe2refresh.setRefreshing(false);

        }
    });

    DataFromExchange();
    //ListView list=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

}

public void updateList(ArrayList<String> price){
    ListView list= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list) ;
    CoinAdapter adapter= new CoinAdapter(this,R.layout.coin_layout,price);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
}

public  void DataFromExchange(){
    String URL="https://bitbns.com/order/getTickerAll";
    //////////below line is showing me the error after 3 second.
    RequestQueue requestQueue= Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    JsonArrayRequest objreq = new JsonArrayRequest(
            Request.Method.GET,
            URL,
            null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    getDataFromExchange Getprice= new getDataFromExchange();
                    price= Getprice.getDataFromBitbnsExchange(response);
                    String str="";
                    for(String p : price)
                        str+=p + " ";
                    Log.e("price from API response" ,str);
                    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                    updateList(price);

                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.e("error response" ,error.toString());
                    Toast.makeText(BitbnsPrice.this," Network error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            }

    );

    requestQueue.add(objreq);

    final Handler handler = new Handler();

    Runnable refresh = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            new BitbnsPrice().DataFromExchange();
            handler.postDelayed(this, 3 * 1000);
        }
    };

    handler.postDelayed(refresh, 3 * 1000);
}

}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with handler. Are you using cache somewhere in your code?

Comment: no,,, this is working for the first time. but after 3 seconds the app crashes with the above error. So i thought there must be some error with handler.

Comment: can you add `requestQueue.setShouldCache(false);` before adding objreq in it?

Comment: Thanks but , i did the following thing and it worked .........private final Handler handler = new Handler();

    private void doTheAutoRefresh() {
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                DataFromExchange();
                doTheAutoRefresh();
            }
        }, 2000);
    }... and in the onCreate method i called the function doTheAutoRefresh

Answer (score 0):

i put the handler in a different function and then i called that from the onCreate method and it worked.

here is the changed code. This works perfectly fine.

```
private final Handler handler = new Handler();

private void doTheAutoRefresh() {
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            DataFromExchange();
            doTheAutoRefresh();
        }
    }, 2000);
}

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    doTheAutoRefresh(); //// added code

    swipe2refresh= (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipe2refresh);
    swipe2refresh.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            swipe2refresh.setRefreshing(true);
            DataFromExchange();
            swipe2refresh.setRefreshing(false);

        }
    });

    DataFromExchange();
    //ListView list=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

}
```